# Single word for "Reading message with sender's accent"

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call it, when someone is reading a message(like SMS/whatsapp) with sender's accent? 
By imagining how the sender should have pronounced, reader reads with same accent.

> He is ____ the message, everyone around him got reminded of the sender.

I thought of using the word 'imitating'. But I feel, it didn't suit.

Comment: *He is impersonating...* would also work http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impersonate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*mimicking*

> verb:
>   **mimic** ;
>   3rd person present: *mimics*; past tense: *mimicked*; past participle: *mimicked*; gerund or present participle: *mimicking*
>   1.
>   imitate (someone or their actions or words), typically in order to entertain or ridicule.
>   "she mimicked Eileen's voice"
>   (**compiled from sources by Google**)

See also: **[mimic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mimic)** on ODOL

Comment: Mimic is used with other situations as well. But I need a word which is specific to mentioned situation.

Comment: @Balu_Madaraju this answer is correct. There might not be any word specific to mimicking the sender's accent.

Comment: I agree with mimic. This is a particular idiomatic use of that word. If I am just putting on a small accent to convey a sense of person and place while reading a letter from my sister to my mom, I call that mimicking. However, if I am overdoing it for humorous effect, then I am parodying it.

Comment: Please add appropriate attribution for your quote. I tried googling part of your quote but I cannot find the exact quote online.

Comment: @JJJ Usually it is the Oxford (cited above) that Google quotes; though at times (as in this case) it is compiled by Google from various sources.